# Uploading file using MVC2, ios6 on the ipad

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-mvc-4, ios6

I have a MVC2 web application in which i have a view containing a simple form as follows:

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "frmAddNewObservationPhoto" }))
  {%>
    <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken()%>
    <strong>1. Enter Photo Description</strong><br />
    <%= Html.TextArea("photoDescription", Model.photoDescription, new { @style = "height: 100px", @id = "photoDescription" })%><br />
    <strong>
        2. Browse New Photo:<br />
        <%= Html.HiddenFor(x => x.questionNo)%>
        <%= Html.HiddenFor(x => x.observationID)%>        
        <input id="file" type="file" name="file">
        <a class="resolveTask" href="javascript:AddNewObservationPhoto()"></a><br />
        Or Select Saved Photo: <br />         
    </strong> 
    <br />
<%} %>
```

I have tested on desktop browsers (firefox, IE, Chrome) and the the file the user selects is posted to my action correctly.  My action code begins as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddNewObservationPhoto(Guid observationID, string photoDescription, decimal questionNo)
    {
        TaskFireObservations fireObservation = FireHelper.GetObservationByID(observationID, _session);

        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
```

For completion the javascript is as follows:

```
function AddNewObservationPhoto() {
   var photoDescription = $('#photoDescription').val();
   if (photoDescription.length == 0) {
       alert('Please enter the photo description');
   }
   else {
       $('#frmAddNewObservationPhoto').submit();           
   }
```

};

My problem is that when i test this on an iPad version 6.0.1 (hence mobile safari browser), there are no files posted to the action.  I have tested on the chrome browser for the ipad and it works fine on there.  Ive also tested on an online ipad emulator and it works; i.e. the selected file is posted to the action and then saved to the relevant location.

Does anyone know why this would be happening? I hope ive explained the issue clearly enough.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi again.  Ive had several views of my question but no answer.  Is there any advice somebody can give regarding my issue?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am putting this down to a bug in mobile safari as this happens intermittently, i.e. on some occasions the file is posted and on others it does nothing.